# How to Edit a Row in a GridView bounded to a LINQ Query with Anonymouse Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, gridview

I use c# asp-net 4 and ef4.

I have a LINQ query which create an Anonymuse Type:

```
var queryRelatedContentsCategories = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                                     from category in cnt.CmsCategories
                                     join c in context.CmsCategories
                                     on cnt.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
                                     join t in context.CmsTypes
                                     on cnt.TypeContent equals t.TypeContent
                                     join m in context.CmsModes
                                     on cnt.ModeContent equals m.ModeContent
                                     select new
                                     {
                                     cnt.ContentId,
                                     ContentTitle = cnt.Title,
                                     ContentCategoryTitle = c.Title,
                                     ContentCategoryTitleAssociation = category.Title,
                                     ContentIsPublished = cnt.IsPublished,
                                     TypeContentDescription = t.Description,
                                     ModeContentDescription = m.Description
                                     };
```

And a GridView bounded to LINQ query:

```
<asp:GridView ID="uxManageRelatedContentsCategories" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowEditing="uxManageRelatedContentsCategories_RowEditing" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="uxManageRelatedContentsCategories_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowupdating="uxManageRelatedContentsCategories_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentId" HeaderText="ContentId" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentTitle" HeaderText="ContentTitle" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentCategoryTitle" HeaderText="CategoryContentTitle"
                ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContentCategoryTitleAssociation">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uxContentCategoryTitleAssociationDispalyer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContentCategoryTitleAssociation") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="uxContentCategoryTitleAssociationCurrentDispalyer" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContentCategoryTitleAssociation") %>'></asp:Label>

                    <asp:ListBox ID="uxCategoryIdNewSelector" runat="server" DataSourceID="uxEntityDataSourceListCategoriesPublished"
                        DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="CategoryId"></asp:ListBox>
                    <act:ListSearchExtender ID="uxCategoryIdNewSelector_ListSearchExtender" runat="server"
                        Enabled="True" IsSorted="True" QueryPattern="Contains" TargetControlID="uxCategoryIdNewSelector">
                    </act:ListSearchExtender>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorListNewCategory" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage="Title field is required." ControlToValidate="uxCategoryIdNewSelector">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="ContentIsPublished" HeaderText="ContentIsPublished"
                ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeContentDescription" HeaderText="TypeContentDescription"
                ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModeContentDescription" HeaderText="ModeContentDescription"
                ReadOnly="True" />
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            Item not found.
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Till now all is working fine.

I need to change a row when a User put the GridView in Edit Mode.

My problem is: **I am not able to see the DataItem for the GridView so I cannot retrieve the value inserted by the User in GridView event:**

> onrowupdating

I understand that Anonymous Type are read only and at the moment I take the values from the GridView using FindControl and Cell property for the Row being edited.

```
// Retrieve the row being edited.
GridViewRow row = uxManageRelatedContentsCategories.Rows[uxManageRelatedContentsCategories.EditIndex];
// Retrieve Value in WebControls
ListBox listCategories = (ListBox)row.FindControl("uxCategoryIdNewSelector");
int myContentId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);
int myCategoryIdSelected = Convert.ToInt32(listCategories.SelectedValue);
Label myCurrentCategoryTitleLink = (Label)row.FindControl("uxContentCategoryTitleAssociationCurrentDispalyer");
```

My question:

How to retrieve values bounded to GridView from an Anonymous Type without look for Cell Property or a Label?

Would be great have a sample of code. Thanks guys for your help as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "ViewModel" class that looks like the anonymous type you have and use that instead.

With a concrete class you will be able to cast the object into the ViewModel and perform whatever you want to do.

Comment: i do not use MVC but WebForms

Comment: Well, I call i "ViewModel" just because its a class that is only used in presentation. But its just a normal class instead of the anonymous type you have. instead of `new { ... }` use `new MyPresentationClass { ... }` and you will be able to cast the `DataItem` object in your event handler.